# AttributeError: can't set attribute error in geometry_msgs/Pose in ROS

Tags: python

I am trying to use [geometry_msgs/Pose](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Pose.html) in a ROS python package. But it is showing following error-

```
AttributeError: can't set attribute error
```

Below is the snippet from the code-

```
ee_pose['position'].x += -0.5
ee_pose['position'].y += -0.5
```

I modified the above lines but I am looking for better way

```
ee_pose=Pose(position=Point(x=ee_pose['position'].x-0.5,
                            y=ee_pose['position'].y-0.5,
                            z=ee_pose['position'].z),
     orientation=Quaternion(x=ee_pose['orientation'].x,
                            y=ee_pose['orientation'].y,
                            z=ee_pose['orientation'].z,
                            w=ee_pose['orientation'].w))
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? Did you already fix it?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: `ee_pose['position'].x += -0.5` line is showing `AttributeError: can't set attribute`. My workaround is given in question as well.

Comment: Would better if you `print(ee_pose)` and post the full traceback

Comment: It is a `dict`. The syntax is `pose = {'position': (x, y, z), 'orientation': (x, y, z, w)}` You can see the other details [here](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Pose.html)

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: `print ee_pose` is returning `{'position': Point(x=0.1340, y=1.2096, z=0.3766), 'orientation': Quaternion(x=0.7468, y=-0.5236, z=-0.2663, w=-0.3115)}`. Also `print ee_pose['position'].x` is returning `0.1340` but `ee_pose['position'].x += -0.5` line is showing `AttributeError: can't set attribute` error. Even `ee_pose['position'].x = ee_pose['position'].x -0.5` is returning the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Position` and `Quaternion` of `geometry_msgs/Pose` in *ROS* use [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) to store their values, so once an instance of `Pose` has been created, it cannot be modified; tuples are *immutable*.

To avoid repeating yourself, you can create new `Pose`s from old ones using a function; like the one below:

```
def update_pose(pose, **kwargs):
    new_pose = Pose(position = Point(
                                x=pose['position'].x + kwargs.get('px', 0),
                                y=pose['position'].y + kwargs.get('py', 0),
                                z=pose['position'].z + kwargs.get('pz', 0)),
                    orientation = Quaternion(
                                x=pose['orientation'].x + kwargs.get('qx', 0),
                                y=pose['orientation'].y + kwargs.get('qy', 0),
                                z=pose['orientation'].z + kwargs.get('qz', 0),
                                w=pose['orientation'].w + kwargs.get('qw', 0)))
    return new_pose
```

The function takes positions as `px`, `py`, `pz` and quaternions as `qx`, `qy`, `qz`, `qw`.

---

And can be used as:

```
ee_pose = update_pose(ee_pose, px=-0.5, py=-0.5)
print(ee_pose)
# {'position': Point(x=-0.366, y=0.7096, z=0.3766), 'orientation': Quaternion(x=0.7468, y=-0.5236, z=-0.2663, w=-0.3115)}
```

Values that are not specified will *default* to `0`, and *signs* of the positions and quaternions must be specified while passing them as parameters.

Comment: Perfect. Happy to know about `collections.namedtuple`. Thank you very much.